# I want the loop of numbers in pyramid pattern by edit form code below

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to change the following code

```
NSString* loop = @"";

for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{ 
    loop = [loop stringByAppendingString:@"0"];
    NSLog(@" %@", loop);
}

for (int i = 10; i >= 1; i--)
{
    loop = [loop substringFromIndex:1];
    NSLog(@" &@", loop);
}
```

to be result in the pattern of pyramid below. What should I do?

```
     1
    101
   21012
  3210123
 432101234
```

and

```
0
01
012
0123
01234
012345
01234
0123
012
01
0
```

Comment: For the first pattern, have a look at this: http://javaprogramwale.blogspot.se/2011/08/pattern-1.html (scroll down a bit and you will find a solution. It's for java, but I assume that you can translate)

Comment: Looks like common homework for a programming course. You sure would not let the SO users do your homework, right?!  ;-)  - SCNR.

Comment: the first pattern in the first line should be `1`? not `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For second pattern you can use code:

```
  NSString *loop=@"";
  for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    if (i > 5) {
      loop = [loop substringToIndex:[loop length] - 1];
    }
    else {
      loop = [loop stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
    }
    NSLog (@" %@" , loop);
  }
```

For first

```
  NSString *loop = @"";
  NSString *spaces = @"     ";
  for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
  {
    if (i==1) {
      loop = [loop stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i", [spaces substringFromIndex:i], i - 1]];
    } else {
      loop = [loop substringFromIndex:6 - i];
      loop = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i",[spaces substringFromIndex:i], i - 1] stringByAppendingString:[loop stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i - 1]]];
    }
    NSLog(@" %@", loop);
  }
```